# Converting a log analysis script from Python to Nim

Tags: nim-lang

Nim looks (very) close to Python, but I am still having a hard time translating the following script:

```
import sys

months = { "Jan": 1, "Feb": 2, "Mar": 3, "Apr": 4, "May": 5, "Jun": 6,
           "Jul": 7, "Aug": 8, "Sep": 9, "Oct": 10, "Nov": 11, "Dec": 12 }

months_r = { v:k for k,v in months.items() }

totals = {}

for line in sys.stdin:
    if "redis" in line and "Partial" in line:
        f1, f2 = line.split()[:2]
        w = (months[f1], int(f2))
        totals[w] = totals.get(w, 0) + 1

for k in sorted(totals.keys()):
    print(months_r[k[0]], k[1], totals[k])
```

Even after reading the Manual for a few hours, I am still unsure about tuples and the way to convert the month names back and forth (my attempts with a table have failed, I did not manage to access the table like it is done in Python).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have good news. Nim code is lot longer then python code, but anyway here is my implementation, eventhough i do not understand what your program should do.

```py
import tables, strutils, os, parseutils, algorithm

var months = {"Jan": 1, "Feb": 2, "Mar": 3, "Apr": 4, "May": 5, "Jun": 6,
        "Jul": 7, "Aug": 8, "Sep": 9, "Oct": 10, "Nov": 11, "Dec": 12}.toTable

var invertedMonths: Table[int, string]

for k, v in months:
    invertedMonths[v] = k

var totals: Table[(int, int), int]

while true:
    let line = readLine(stdin)
    if line.strip == "": break
    if "redis" in line and "Partial" in line:
        let args = line.split()
        let w = (months[args[0]], parseInt(args[1]))
        totals[w] = totals.getOrDefault(w, 0) + 1

var keys = newSeq[(int, int)](totals.len)

keys.setLen(0)

for k in totals.keys():
    keys.add(k)

# i have no idea how python would sort this
keys.sort(proc(a, b: (int, int)): int =
    a[0] + a[1] - b[0] - b[1]
)

for k in keys:
    echo invertedMonths[k[0]], " ", k[1], " ", totals[k]
```

### edit

After some advice is restructures code as follows and length looks lot better now.

```py
import tables, strutils, algorithm, sequtils

var months = {"Jan": 1, "Feb": 2, "Mar": 3, "Apr": 4, "May": 5, "Jun": 6,
        "Jul": 7, "Aug": 8, "Sep": 9, "Oct": 10, "Nov": 11, "Dec": 12}.toTable

var invertedMonths: Table[int, string]

for k, v in months: invertedMonths[v] = k

var totals: Table[(int, int), int]

for line in stdin.lines:
    if line.strip == "": break
    if "redis" in line and "Partial" in line:
        let args = line.split()
        let w = (months[args[0]], parseInt(args[1]))
        totals[w] = totals.getOrDefault(w, 0) + 1

for k in toSeq(totals.keys).sorted:
    echo invertedMonths[k[0]], " ", k[1], " ", totals[k]
```

Comment: gets shorter if `let invertedMonths = collect(initTable,for k,v in months:{v:k})`

Comment: that while loop and the next two lines can just be `for line in stdin.lines`

Comment: Choosing to make the code longer for readability is a completely valid choice, but then why imply it's due to some inherent limitation of Nim?

Comment: the keys stuff doesn't need to be there, tuples can be sorted just fine.  could be `for k in toSeq(totals.keys).sorted:`

Comment: The output part can be written as `for k in sorted(toSeq(totals.keys)): echo …` (Edit: ninja'd by shirleyquirk)

Comment: oh boy i have to fix it all, my knowlage of nim is poor i see

Comment: no way! it's great! just trying to curate ;-)

Comment: ist all fixed now

Comment: you'll need to import `sequtils` for that `toSeq`

Comment: but i did import it

Comment: i'm both blind and a fool

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232090/discussion-between-shirleyquirk-and-jakub-doka).

Answer (score 4):

Just being silly now, but I couldn't leave this alone without refactoring it to use an enum instead of the month tables

```
import tables, strutils, algorithm,sequtils

type Month = enum Jan=1,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec

var totals: CountTable[(Month, int)]

for line in stdin.lines:
  if "redis" in line and "Partial" in line:
        let flds = line.split()
        inc totals,(flds[0].parseEnum[:Month], flds[1].parseInt)

for k in toSeq(totals.keys).sorted:
    echo k[0], " ", k[1], " ", totals[k]
```

Edit: had to nick @xbello's solution using the CountTable, too good.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is to convert the month name between the number and the tree letter? Nim has this:

```
import times

echo Month(2)                        # February
echo ($Month(2))[.. 2]               # Feb
echo parse("Feb", "MMM").month       # February
echo ord(parse("Feb", "MMM").month)  # 2
```

Then for the counting you can do this:

```
import tables, times

var totals = initCountTable[(Month, int)]()

# The following is some sample data, you just get each
# tuple[Mont, int] from your parsed file
var sample = @[
  (m: 1.Month, i: 3),
  (m: 2.Month, i: 3),
  (m: 1.Month, i: 1),
  (m: 1.Month, i: 3),
  (m: 12.Month, i: 2)]

for item in sample:
  totals.inc(s)

echo totals
# {(January, 3): 2, (February, 3): 1, (January, 1): 1, (December, 2): 1}
```

Finally, the sorting. As I understand, this is sorted alphabetically per month name, and the ties per int. I have the impression that you want to sort per month number instead of name, thus all the table gimnastics. Nim will sort per month number if you used `Month` as the table key:

```
import algorithm

echo sorted(@[12.Month, 1.Month, 6.Month])
#@[January, June, December]
```

---

Putting it all together, and assuming you have a log file that follows the pattern "Month Day Message" like:

```
Jan 1 Log Message Partial redis
Mar 31 A Partial redis in the same date
Jan 02 More Log Messages but not captured
Mar 31 Even More Log Messages Partial redis
Jan 15 An out of order message Partial redis
```

This can be done in **5** clean lines, 9 if you count variable declarations and imports:

```
import algorithm, sequtils, strscans, strutils, tables, times

var totals = initCountTable[(Month, int)]()
var month, msg: string
var day: int

for l in stdin.lines:
  if scanf(l, "$w $i $*", month, day, msg) and "redis" in l and "Partial" in l:
    totals.inc (parse(month, "MMM").month, day)

for k in sorted(toSeq(totals.keys())):
  echo k, ": ", totals[k]
```

Results:

```
(January, 1): 1
(January, 15): 1
(March, 31): 2
```

Comment: CountTable! never saw that before, perfect.

Comment: and i think the first two fields might be Month Day, so `parse(line,"MMM d")` would work if it weren't for the fact that DateTime doesn't have a hash

Comment: Depending on the input, I think the Nim code could be around 6-8 lines. But you have to know the batteries, and it takes time.